# Delete files with backslash in linux

Tags: linux, shell, rm

I accidentally created a file which name is a backslash `\`:

```
>ls -l
total 0
-rw-rw---- 1 user group  0 Jul  3 21:34 \
```

How do I delete it?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a programming issue. Ask on [unix.se]

Comment: @HoboSapiens: I'm torn. The OP's goal is not programming-related, but the underlying problem is with the shell syntax, and the solution is to understand shell syntax better. So while it would certainly be a better fit on Super User or Unix & Linux (where it would probably actually be a dupe), I think it's probably fine on Stack Overflow.

Comment: This is the first search result for various searches along the lines of "linux remove backslash filename".
It's an incredibly-frustrating issue for programmers who mis-type something since the solution isn't always intuitive. I recommend leaving this solution available to us clutzy typists.

Comment: see also: https://superuser.com/questions/625608/how-can-i-remove-a-file-or-directory-called

Answer (score 13):

In order to pass a backslash in an argument to a command, you need to "quote" or "escape" it, which you can do either by wrapping it with single-quotes:

```
rm '\'
```

or by prefixing it with another backslash:

```
rm \\
```

(The same sort of thing is needed if you, say, have a file named `*`. To delete it, you would write `rm '*'` or `rm \*` or `rm "*"`. And similarly for most other special characters.)